# Macs connecting to Windows File share

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mac-osx

So, we have Mac users who connect to our Windows file shares. When they open the first time, they are connected without issue, but if they were to close the finder window and try to open it up again, it will just say connecting and never actually connect.

Does anyone know why that is? The file share is on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac leaves the connection after exiting Finder window, So to initiate it again they should select the shared server on the "Shared" list of Finder quick access bar.

This only happend on SMB  (Samba) since Mac doesn't like SAMBA that much.